# Using recursion with map in python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to learn functional programming concepts. 
An exercise,  Flatten a nested list using map/reduce.
My code.

```
lists = [ 1 , 2 , [ 3 , 4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9] ]
def flatten(lists):
      return map(lambda x: flatten(x) if isinstance(x,list) else x, lists)

print flatten(lists)
```

I get  output same as input. What did i do wrong ?
How recursion works with map() ?

Comment: Hint: you are not using `reduce()`.

Comment: @s007, Can you share where you are getting these functional programming exercises?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses both `map` and `reduce`:

```
def flatten(seq):
    return reduce(operator.add, map(
        lambda x: flatten(x) if isinstance(x,list) else [x],
        seq))
```

As Martijn said, map produces the same number of items out as it receives on its input, so the outer step needs to be the `reduce` call that produces a single output for all of the inputs. `map` can be used here instead to make all of the input consistent: i.e. a sequence of lists.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a million times.  beautiful solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can't solve this problem *with `map()`*. The recursive calls return a list, so for a list in the input you replaced the result *with another list*. `map()` always has to produce the same number of elements in the output as it was given in the input, after all.

With `reduce()` you can *append* more elements to an existing list:

```
def flatten(lists):
    return reduce(lambda res, x: res + (flatten(x) if isinstance(x, list) else [x]), lists, [])
```

This starts with an empty list, and *appends* elements to that for each element in `lists`. If that element is a list itself, recursion is used.

This produces the expected output:

```
>>> def flatten(lists):
...     return reduce(lambda res, x: res + (flatten(x) if isinstance(x, list) else [x]), lists, [])
...
>>> lists = [ 1 , 2 , [ 3 , 4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9] ]
>>> flatten(lists)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: -Thankyou. It means it can't be solved with map and reduce instead just reduce. Just a thought.

Comment: @s007: it can't. `map()` always produces the same number of outputs as you put into it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `map` in your function it returns a list even when you call call the function in recursively.

So instead of using `map` or `reduce` which are not pythonic ways for flattening a nested list you can use a generator function:

```
>>> def flatten(lists):
...     for sub in lists:
...         if isinstance(sub,list):
...            for i in sub:
...                 yield i
...         else:
...            yield sub
... 
>>> 
>>> list(flatten(lists))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you still want to sue `map` function you can use following approach:

```
>>> def flatten(lists,total=[]):
...       map(lambda x: total.extend(x) if isinstance(x,list) else total.append(x), lists)
...       return total
... 
>>> flatten(lists)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: But the *exercise* was to use `map()` and `reduce()`. Yup, using a generator makes this easy enough, but *that's not what the OP is learning*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right about learning. ButI just said that it's not pythonic, and demonstrate the correct way.Any way I updated the answer with a `map` based approach.

Comment: @Kasramvd Isn't passing total=[] as parameter against function programming principle  ? As it makes it mutable.

Comment: @s007 List objects are mutable in python.

Comment: Yes, but that's at best a comment, with a link to the canonical post on the subject: [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution with just recursion:

```
lists = [ 1 , 2 , [ 3 , 4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9] ]
def flatten(lists):
    return (flatten(lists[0]) + flatten(lists[1:]) if isinstance(lists[0],list) else [lists[0]]+flatten(lists[1:])) if len(lists)>0 else []
```

Comment: Well I would have posted a reduce answer that is what directly comes to mind when flattening a list . This was because reduce was already posted as an answer.